# @IBAction Build Error - cannot execute code to reset an Int value

Tags: xcode, swift3, uialertaction

I am trying to let a user reset his/her game score (a basic `let` value that is initially `0` but I keep getting an error at the last addAction telling me: 
Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type '((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?'

Please help me! Here's the block of code I referred to:

```
@IBAction func resetScore() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Reset", message: "Are you sure you want to reset your game score? All progress will be lost.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Reset", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
        func resetScore() {
            let score = 0
            scoreCounter.text = "Score: " + String(score)
        }
    }))

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because that closure is expecting a parameter. You need to write `_ in` at the end:

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Reset", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { _ in
```

Furthermore, if you expect the `resetScore` function to be called when the button is pressed, then you'll need to update the code to the following:

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Reset", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { _ in
  let score = 0
  self.scoreCounter.text = "Score: " + String(score)
}))
```

Also, based on this core you are declaring a new local variable with the `let scope` line, which means you are not resetting anything. I'm guessing you have a instance variable called `scope`, so the following will do:

```
self.score = 0
self.scoreCounter.text = "Score: " + String(score)
```

Comment: If my answer to your question was helpful and was fulfilling, then please accept it as the answer to your post to indicate towards other users that your issue has been resolved :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work